# Is there anyway I can find out the viewcontroller being shown on the screen in the app without using viewWillAppear/viewWillDisappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, swift

I am trying to find the page the user is viewing at a given point of time. Is this possible without making any call from viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad. I have tried keywindow but it works only for navigation controller and it doesnt work as expected for tabBarController or a containerView.
Thank you.

Comment: add an NSLog message to test or create a label and reference an int using prepare for segue so it can upcount.

Comment: in tab bar controller can find using selected index of the tab bar.

Comment: @VelmuruganS the selected index is returning the index of the controller which was present earlier, i.e., if I am going from index 1 to index 3, it is displaying the index as 1 instead of 3

Comment: @SASmith is there any other way where I can find it without adding any code in the viewcontroller or the segues, like from the appdelegate?

Comment: I am unsure why you are reluctant to use anything in viewDidLoad or others. Can you explain at all? That may help.

Comment: @SASmith I have many screens in my app and I am looking to add a new functionality where I can find which screen is being viewed by the user. I am trying to minimize the effort instead of adding the code in each view controller.

Comment: So number each view with an NSLog and copy paste into each viewcontroller. That wouod be the easiest way.

Comment: @SASmith yes that would reduce the difficulty but I wanted to find out if it is possible without touching the current application code. Maybe I am missing something in the basics such as presentedViewController or presentingViewController